# Convert given URL to a base URL

Tags: php, url, radix

How can I convert a given url to a base url?
That means if I have "http://test.com/folder/it.html?gsa=5", the script should return "http://test.com/folder/".

I tried:

```
preg_match('~.*/~', $cur_url, $match);
$base=($match[0]=='http://') ? $cur_url : $match;
```

Doesn't work good.

Comment: Actually, the base URL would be `http://test.com/`. Regardless, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You want to strip from the last / character? substr?

Comment: I tried this code, but it does not seem to work right.

preg_match('~.*/~', $cur_url, $match);
$base=($match[0]=='http://') ? $cur_url : $match;

@Matt, no, the base is the url with path, but file, query and fragment removed.

Comment: @user1568625 I don't think you understand what *base URL* means.

Comment: A *non-reliable* simple approach would be `dirname()`. Only works if the URL params don't contain slashes, and strips the "directories" `/` as well.

Comment: @user1568625 A base url is domain of the site(example google.ca not google.ca/maps). What you requested was the base url plus the directories minus the file from a url. That is much harder than base url, but I think I might have an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try `parse_url`

Sample from php.net

```
<?php $url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); ?>
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: The PATH keeps also the file at the end. I has to be removed. Also I need a base url generated, not just path.

Comment: That's a lot of work to reassemble the base URL. Question looks like OP wants just `it.html` trimmed, and retain the base "path" of the resource locator.

Comment: Exactly. But `[path]` will require further string patching. Your `parse_url` example will return `/folder/it.html`

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex string that keeps everything from the .com forward. Just set it up so any of your possible site endings can be used. Will update shortly with sample string.

--EDIT--

This php regex string works to get the base address from any url(ive tested).

```
![a-zA-Z]+(.com/|.ca/|.gov/)!
```

Note: this string is set to only work with .com, .ca, and .gov domains, but you can add others in the brackets separating them with |.

--EDIT--

Rereading your post, I have designed another string for if you want everything in the url except the file at the end.

```
!([a-zA-Z]*+(.com/|.ca/|.gov/))+([a-zA-Z/]*[/])!
```

Note: If you use this with urls that don't have a file on the end, the directory must have the slash still or the last directory will be cut as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to remove the $_GET vars from the url

`?hello=somethin&something=somethingelse`

The the following might work:

```
$fullurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlarray = explode($fullurl, "?");
$urlnoget = $urlarray[0];
```

that will explode the url into bits for every ? and there are no ? in an actual file/fooledr name so it will clear out the $_GET urls.

Have you considered using JavaScript?

Sorry if there are easier ways but this is what I know.

Comment: Ive never heard of such a function, well I am fairly new here. PS:+1 if my post is useful